# Determine element is at bottom of viewport and add class to it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, position, offset

need some help here. I need to determine when a certain element is at bottom position of the viewport and then to add fixed class to it. So on scroll down add class when element is at bottom 0 and remove class when i scroll back up.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
            var $el = $('.content-btn-row');
            if ($($el).position().top + $($el).height()) {
                console.log("bottom!");
                $(".content-btn-row").addClass("fixed");
            } else {
                $(".scontent-btn-row").removeClass("fixed");
            }
        });
```

Comment: $el.position().top + $el.height()==$(window).height() maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO we should take into account inner height of a window's content area (it can be different that window height) and check if document has been scrolled.
`window.innerHeight` - returns the inner height of a window's content area
`window.pageYOffset` - returns the pixels the current document has been scrolled (vertically) from the upper left corner of the window
If the element is below viewport at the beginning this code should be ok:

```
var elem = window.innerHeight + $($el).height(); //position of the element
var winScroll = window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset; //viewport height + scroll
if (elem) >= (winScroll) {
            console.log("bottom!");
                $(".content-btn-row").addClass("fixed");
            } else {
                $(".scontent-btn-row").removeClass("fixed");
            } 
}
```

and it will be better to check if there is a class "fixed" with `hasClass` before we add or remove it.

Comment: Close but not quite there :)  http://jsbin.com/woxuparohe/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score -1):

Why are you comparing the variables by adding same constant values(window.innerHeight) to them?

```
var elem =  $($el).height();
var winScroll = window.pageYOffset;
if (elem) >= (winScroll) {
    console.log("bottom!");
    $(".content-btn-row").addClass("fixed");
} else {
    $(".scontent-btn-row").removeClass("fixed");
}}
```

By this way we can reduce some complexity and code